# LeetCode - проблема с проверкой результата

Tags: алгоритм, сервер, golang, backend, task

Я тут, в общем, решил качать мозги и порешать задачки на LeetCode. Проблема в том, что у меня есть вопросы к самому сервису, а не задачам. Допустим, вот есть задача про Rotate Array, мое решение выглядит как-то так (пусть оно даже неверное):

[image: код]

Проблема в том, что сама система не ждет возрата результата и как бы я не пытался - всегда выдает мне результат, что изначально сама и заложила в числах. В чем прикол? Что я должен сделать, ведь я решил, а программа не хочет видеть мое решение. Когда-то уже сталкивался с такой же проблемой на Яндекс Практикум. Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Ссылку на задачу дайте. Подозреваю в задании сказано что нужно изменить переданный слайс, а не вернуть новый.

Comment: судя по всему, это [189 задача](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/).

Comment: О, у меня даже решена эта задача. Правда на JS =)

Comment: у меня тоже:) `Runtime: 0 ms, faster than 100.00% of C++ online submissions for Rotate Array.
Memory Usage: 9.8 MB, less than 77.91% of C++ online submissions for Rotate Array.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело не совсем  в сервисе.

На Python будет то же самое, если заводить новый список, а не менять элементы существующего

После `nums = arr_l` адрес списка **изменится**, а проверяющая система смотрит на старое место. Таким образом, мы нарушаем вторую часть предостережения: `Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.`

Если напечатать `nums` - мы изменения увидим, а проверялка - нет.

Проверенный на Leetcode вариант на Python:

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        def reverse(l, r):
            while l < r:
                nums[l], nums[r] = nums[r], nums[l]
                l+=1
                r-=1
        le = len(nums)        
        k = k % le        
        reverse(0, le - k - 1)
        reverse(le - k, le - 1)
        reverse(0, le - 1)
```

Comment: А есть пример как мне это побороть? Я уже просто пробовал слайсы изменять и все-равно результат тоже. Просто я рассчитываю, что работа с индексами массива никак не влияет на изначальную ссылку. В итоге результат тот ж

Comment: Голанга я не знаю, а в Питоне вместо сборки нового nums из половинок сделал по классике - развернул обе части списка, потом весь список, всё это делал на месте, просто обменивая элементы. При этом экземпляр nums остался на прежнем месте, и всё заработало

Comment: Добавил код для справки

Comment: Спасибо. Засчитаю за ответ, буду разбираться)